# Mat constructor asserts an error in openCV

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I have problem with `Mat` constructor
Run under win7x32, compiled openCV 2.2.0 (no matter here?!)
For example, I have the next main code, where problem is:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
     const char* filename = "test.bmp";

     IplImage* img = cvLoadImage(filename, 1); // works OK
     cvShowImage("hello openCV", img); // works OK

     Mat image(img); // asserting HERE !
     //... the next is out of problem
     ...
     return 0;
}
```

Here's is console\terminal output:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((((img) != __null && ((const IplImage*)(img))->nSize == sizeof(IplImage)) && ((IplImage*)img)->imageData != __null) && img->imageData != 0) in Mat, file D:\OpenCV-2.2.0\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 427
```

Comment: Take a look at this webpage, sometimes you just need to pay attention into the basic structures. http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html

Comment: I've found example there:                                                                       IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("greatwave.png", 1);
Mat mtx(img); // convert IplImage* -> Mat

Comment: do **not** use opencv2.2, do **not** use IplImage* .please, stop living under a rock.

Comment: The answer to your problem is to read your image as a `Mat` so you don't have to convert.